# how to insert into two tables using php with transaction?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I know inserting into multiple tables with single query is not possible,

now I am trying to insert into 2 tables with php using `START TRANSACTION` but its not working.

my sql query is looks like

```
mysqli_query($con,"START TRANSACTION
    INSERT INTO users VALUES ('', '$getuser', '$getpass', '$getemail', '$fname', '$lname', '$domain', '$address1', '$address2', '$city', '$country', '$region', '$zip', '$phone', '$getplan', '$duration', '$getprice', '', '0', '0', '$code', '$date', '$time','0', '', '')
    INSERT INTO domains (username) VALUES ('$getuser') COMMIT");
```

So where is the problem??

many thanks in advance.

Comment: I maybe wrong, but your insert statement seems wrong to me. shouldn't it be INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);?

Comment: and what you see?? isn't it seems like as you mention?

Comment: please read this on how to insert using correct syntax http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is because `mysqli_query` can handle only one comand each time. Split them like:

```
mysqli_query($con, "SET AUTOCOMMIT=0");
mysqli_query($con,"START TRANSACTION");
$insert1 = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO users VALUES ('', '$getuser', '$getpass', '$getemail', '$fname', '$lname', '$domain', '$address1', '$address2', '$city', '$country', '$region', '$zip', '$phone', '$getplan', '$duration', '$getprice', '', '0', '0', '$code', '$date', '$time','0', '', '')");
$insert2 = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO domains (username) VALUES ('$getuser')");

if($insert1 && $insert2) {
    mysqli_query($con,"COMMIT");
} else {
    mysqli_query($con,"ROLLBACK");
}
mysqli_query($con, "SET AUTOCOMMIT=1");
```

---

**update**: if you are using mysqli the objectorientated way, you can do the following:

```
$mysqli->begin_transaction();
$insert1 = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('', '$getuser', '$getpass', '$getemail', '$fname', '$lname', '$domain', '$address1', '$address2', '$city', '$country', '$region', '$zip', '$phone', '$getplan', '$duration', '$getprice', '', '0', '0', '$code', '$date', '$time','0', '', '')");
$insert2 = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO domains (username) VALUES ('$getuser')");

if($insert1 && $insert2) {
    $mysqli->commit();
} else {
    $mysqli->rollback();
}
```

*HINT*: if you use an older PHP version as 5.5.0, you can't use `$mysqli->begin_transaction();` and have to use `$mysqli->autocommit(false);` at the begining and `$mysqli->autocommit(true);` at the end instead

Comment: is this `mysql_query("SET AUTOCOMMIT=0");` or `mysqli_query("SET AUTOCOMMIT=0");` ???

Comment: but all of this is separate queries, not in single query.

it should in 1 query with transaction.

how to do that?

Comment: yes, but because of `AUTOCOMMIT` is off and `START TRANSACTION` they will be handled in one transaction.

Comment: OK, if it works I will accept your answer. 

and if you think my question is helpful, you can upvote my question to help me increase my rating. 

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
if($insert1 && $insert2)
```

name it just "insert" and then:

```
if ($insert->affected_rows > 0)
```